# Как называется упрощение слов?

Tags: лексика

Как называется упрощение слов? Например, сельдь-селёдка, морковь-морковка, редис-редиска и т. п.

Как это правильно называется?

Answer (score 2):

Порядок преобразования базового слова посредством суфф. форм в слово его ряда называется диминутивным.

> Диминути́в или деминути́в (от лат. deminutus «уменьшенный»),
>   уменьши́тельная фо́рма — слово, или форма слова, передающие
>   субъективно-оценочное значение малого объёма, размера и т. п., обычно
>   выражаемое посредством уменьшительных аффиксов, напр.: шка́фчик,
>   до́мик, клю́чик, статуэ́тка. Значение уменьшительности также может
>   сопровождаться различными эмоционально-экспрессивными окрасками —
>   ласкательности (уменьшительно-ласкательная форма), напр.: дочу́рка,
>   маму́ся.

Образованное таким образом слово имеет возможность занимать свою особую нишу в однокоренных синонимических рядах, например: дева – девка – девица – девушка; баба – бабка – бабушка; пъта – птица – птичка.

Answer (score 2):

В словообразовательном словаре   Ефремовой рассматривается **суффикс К со значением единичного предмета**, отнесенного к массе вещества или к однородным предметам:

*морковь — морковка, редис — редиска, малина — малинка, вата — ватка, бумага — бумажка, железо — железка, шоколад — шоколадка.*

Поэтому это **не упрощение, а выделение единичных предметов**.

Comment: Редиска, морковка и особенно малинка – вовсе не "выделение единичных предметов". Это уменьшительная форма.

Comment: Можно взять одну редиску, одну морковку, одну малинку. РЕДИСКА, -и; ; ж. 1. =Редис. 2. ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ корнеплод редиса. Грызть с хрустом редиску. собир. ПУЧОК РЕДИСКИ. Приготовить салат из редиски..